# Is it possible to use a generic type to receive the String and NSString Type parameters?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, nsstring

Recently, I am working on the new UI of our company's product. And to resize the text size for iphone 6 plus is really a problem for me. I even haven't found an elegant way. However, I am intrigued by some digression that I called the "bonus" during a mission. (In fact, this is my major doubt for this question).

The solution for text size I figure out is by using fontdescriptor to change point size , so that I can apply this trick for any font style. And I use Bond binding to observer text changes.

```
lazy var bondFontSizeForIP6P = Bond<(NSAttributedString, UILabel)>{ (s, label) in
    if SRDevice.getVersion == .IPHONE6PLUS{
        let scaleFactor:CGFloat = 1.3
        let fd = label.font.fontDescriptor()
        let pointSize = fd.pointSize * scaleFactor
        let font = UIFont(descriptor: fd, size: pointSize)
        label.font = font
    }
}

zip(cell.distanceLabel.dynAttributedText, cell.distanceLabel) ->> bondFontSizeForIP6P
```

It works, but it is obviously that it can't cover all the condition, at least the label change the text with string property more frequently. So I think if there is a more generic method to substitue. And I tried to use protocol to imply generics which was mentioned in the realms' articles: [Swift - Enums, Pattern Matching & Generics](https://realm.io/news/swift-enums-pattern-matching-generics/)

```
protocol StringLike {}
extension String:StringLike{}
extension NSAttributedString:StringLike{}
```

I added this protocol and changed my closure `bondFontSizeForIP6P`

```
lazy var bondFontSizeForIP6P = Bond<(StringLike, UILabel)>{ (s, label) in
    if SRDevice.getVersion == .IPHONE6PLUS{
        let scaleFactor:CGFloat = 1.3
        let fd = label.font.fontDescriptor()
        let pointSize = fd.pointSize * scaleFactor
        let font = UIFont(descriptor: fd, size: pointSize)
        label.font = font
    }
}
```

and bind this listener with two observers.

```
zip(cell.distanceLabel.dynAttributedText, cell.distanceLabel) ->> bondFontSizeForIP6P
zip(cell.speedLabel.dynText, cell.speedLabel) ->> bondFontSizeForIP6P
```

Apparently, it's not a successful attempt ,that's why I'm here. The error log is here:

```
Binary operator '->>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Dynamic<(NSAttributedString, UILabel!)>' and 'Bond<(StringLike, UILabel)>'
```

In fact, beside this approche I also attempt another method like changing type to a more original type like Any, AnyObject `Bond<Any>` ,But String isn't AnyObject and NSAttributedString isn't Any.

So my question is that means there is no way to use a generic type to describe String and NSAttributedString, or there is any blind spot I don't realize?